# HTML rowspan height issue

Tags: html, css

Summary

All browsers, by default, stretch the height of the cells inside the  so that the rows are the same size. Simple example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The td rowspan attribute</h1>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="500">Head 1</th>
            <th width="500">Head 2</th>
            <th width="500">Head 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
        <td>Small col</td>
        <td>Small col</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

BUT when you use the rowspan attribute, those columns in which you insert more than 1 cell will no longer be stretched.

Problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The td rowspan attribute</h1>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="500">Head 1</th>
            <th width="500">Head 2</th>
            <th width="500">Head 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Small col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Small col</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Small col</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

So the question is: how to make columns containing more than one cell in a row stretch to the width of the row?

Comment: I guess you're looking for `colspan`. Okay, I am still confused. What are you looking for?

Comment: `rowspan="4" `  when you only have 3 cells doesn't make sense. The single cells without any rowspan also don't make much sense. I would suggest clean up the HTML first so that the output is logical.

Comment: I'm looking for a way that will allow me to display cells in such a way that they stretch to the width of the rows.

Problem example:
https://postimg.cc/4Yx67bvt

Expected result (what I want):
https://postimg.cc/YvBSTp0S

Comment: @cloned No rowspan="4" this is the correct number. If you try to set the value to less, then your table will break

Comment: Sorry I mixed up row- and colspan. Nevertheless, I don't think the html structure is valid. You define 3 columns for each row in the header, you should also have 3 columns now in every table row. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @cloned You don't seem to understand how the rowspan attribute works. rowspan="4" means that this cell should span the size of three rows after itself.

Comment: yeah I looked it up, maybe I don't fully understand it. Sorry, can't really help you there.

Comment: They _are_ stretched. The problem is that the rows of the tbody are of different heights. Because of the missing cells in rows 1 and 2, row 2 is taking most of the vertical space. Can you provide a diagram of what you want to end up with?

Comment: @Alohci Expected result (what I want): postimg.cc/YvBSTp0S